# Filter array and compare but skip null values

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, conditional-statements

I am currently trying to filter available products based on their selected options.

```
const products = [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Safari',
        horsepowers: 30,
        doors: 4,
        gear_type: 'automatic',
        wheels: 6
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Jungle',
        horsepowers: 50,
        doors: 3,
        gear_type: 'automatic',
        wheels: 5
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Moon',
        horsepowers: 30,
        doors: 4,
        gear_type: 'manual',
        wheels: 4
    }
]
```

```
const selectedOptions = 
{
   horsepowers: 50,
   doors: 3,
   gear_type: null,
   wheels: null
}
```

Typically I would do something like

```
const availableProducts = products.filter((product) => 
  product.horsepowers === selectedOptions.horsepowers &&
  product.doors === selectedOptions.doors .... etc
```

however, how do I skip null values, empty arrays, and undefined values if the user has not yet selected all possible options yet?

Comment: why not filter `selectedOptions` to remove the pairs with null values? Then get and iterate over the keys for your other filter test.

Comment: please add some examples of unwanted values.

Comment: Thanks for the many answers. Very helpful all of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next provided approach takes advantage of [the 2nd `thisArg` argument of almost every available prototypal array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#parameters).

Thus one can write a generic filter function which compares any item's property values to the related ones configured by the `selectedOptions` object which will be passed alongside the filter function as `filter`'s 2nd argument and as the filter function's `this` context ...

```js
const selectedOptions = {
  horsepowers: 50,
  doors: 3,
  gear_type: null,
  wheels: null,
};
const products = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Safari',
  horsepowers: 30,
  doors: 4,
  gear_type: 'automatic',
  wheels: 6,
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Jungle',
  horsepowers: 50,
  doors: 3,
  gear_type: 'automatic',
  wheels: 5,
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'Moon',
  horsepowers: 30,
  doors: 4,
  gear_type: 'manual',
  wheels: 4,
}];

function doItemPropertiesEqualEveryBoundSelectedOption(item) {
  return Object
    // create key value pairs from the `this` bound selected options.
    .entries(this)
    // skip/ignore selected option entries where `value` equals `null`.
    .filter(([key, value]) => value !== null)
    // execute item specific selected option validation via `every`.
    .every(([key, value]) => item[key] === value);    
}
console.log(
  products
    .filter(
      doItemPropertiesEqualEveryBoundSelectedOption,
      selectedOptions,
    )
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

In order to answer another of the OP's questions ...

> *"however, how do I skip null values, empty arrays, and undefined values if the user has not yet selected all possible options yet?"*

... and also provide a generic solution to it, the above approach can be changed to a `thisArg` object which not only features the selected options but also the condition of not to be validated (invalid) `selectedOption` properties ...

```js
const products = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Safari',
  horsepowers: 30,
  doors: 4,
  gear_type: 'automatic',
  wheels: 6,
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Jungle',
  horsepowers: 50,
  doors: 3,
  gear_type: 'automatic',
  wheels: 5,
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'Moon',
  horsepowers: 30,
  doors: 4,
  gear_type: 'manual',
  wheels: 4,
}];

const selectedOptions = {
  horsepowers: 50,
  doors: 3,
  gear_type: null,
  wheels: null,
};
const isInvalidValue = (value) => {
  return Array.isArray(value)
    // empty array validation.
    ? (value.length === 0)
    // undefined and null value validation.
    : (value == null)
}

function doItemPropertiesEqualEveryBoundValidOption(item) {
  const { options, isInvalidValue } = this;
  return Object
    .entries(options)
    .filter(([key, value]) => !isInvalidValue(value))
    .every(([key, value]) => item[key] === value);    
}
console.log(
  products
    .filter(
      doItemPropertiesEqualEveryBoundValidOption,
      { options: selectedOptions, isInvalidValue },
    )
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
selectedOptions.horsepowers == null ? true : product.horsepowers === selectedOptions.horsepowers &&
product.doors == null ? true : product.doors === selectedOptions.doors
```

If you want to keep it in line, you can use a ternary operator to check if it's null before comparing.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than typing in each option by hand, you could just iterate over `selectedOptions`. Then it's as simple as checking if the value of each option is null before comparing.

```
let filtered = products.filter(e => {
  for(let [key, value] of Object.entries(selectedOptions))
  {
    if(value != null && e[key] != value)
      return false;
  }
  return true;
});
```

```js
const products = [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Safari',
        horsepowers: 30,
        doors: 4,
        gear_type: 'automatic',
        wheels: 6
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Jungle',
        horsepowers: 50,
        doors: 3,
        gear_type: 'automatic',
        wheels: 5
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Moon',
        horsepowers: 30,
        doors: 4,
        gear_type: 'manual',
        wheels: 4
    }
]

const selectedOptions = 
{
   horsepowers: 50,
   doors: 3,
   gear_type: null,
   wheels: null
}

let filtered = products.filter(e => {
  for(let [key, value] of Object.entries(selectedOptions))
  {
    if(value != null && e[key] != value)
      return false;
  }
  return true;
});

console.log(filtered);
```

However, if you really want to write it out, I'd just check if the option is set with a simple boolean check. `!(null)` returns true, so this would work.

```
return (!selectedOptions.horsepowers || selectedOptions.horsepowers == product.horsepowers) && ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could preprocess `selectedOptions` first and then comparing:

```js
const applicableOptions = Object.entries(selectedOptions).filter(
  ([_, value]) => value !== null && value !== undefined
);

const availableProducts = products.filter((product) =>
  applicableOptions.every(([optKey, optValue]) => product[optKey] === optValue)
);
```

to compare using array, you would need to update your example as there's no array property

Answer (score 1):

- Using [`Object#entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), get the pairs with selected values from `selectedOptions` to use for filtering the products list
- Using `Array#filter` and [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), filter the list to make sure that resulting products match the above pairs

```js
const 
  products = [ { id: 1, name: 'Safari', horsepowers: 30, doors: 4, gear_type: 'automatic', wheels: 6 }, { id: 2, name: 'Jungle', horsepowers: 50, doors: 3, gear_type: 'automatic', wheels: 5 }, { id: 3, name: 'Moon', horsepowers: 30, doors: 4, gear_type: 'manual', wheels: 4 } ],
  selectedOptions = { horsepowers: 50, doors: 3, gear_type: null, wheels: null };

const filterOptions = 
  Object.entries(selectedOptions).filter(([_, value]) => value !== null);
const selectedProducts = 
  products.filter(product =>
    filterOptions.every(([key, value]) => product[key] === value)
  );

console.log(selectedProducts);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could generate a filter array from `selectedOptions` and filter the entries and use this for filtering the data, later.

```js
const
    products = [{ id: 1, name: 'Safari', horsepowers: 30, doors: 4, gear_type: 'automatic', wheels: 6 }, { id: 2, name: 'Jungle', horsepowers: 50, doors: 3, gear_type: 'automatic', wheels: 5 }, { id: 3, name: 'Moon', horsepowers: 30, doors: 4, gear_type: 'manual', wheels: 4 }],
    selectedOptions = { horsepowers: 50, doors: 3, gear_type: null, wheels: null },
    filter = Object
        .entries(selectedOptions)
        .filter(([, v]) => v !== null),
    result = products.filter(o => filter.every(([k, v]) => o[k] === v));

console.log(result);
```